# How to calculate delta v for orbit change around body; not necessarily Earth?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, delta-v

Let me express my joy at having found this great place of Stack Exchange.

My question concerns the calculation of delta v requirements when already in orbit around a body and lowering or raising this orbit as economically as possible (burns at apoapsis or periapsis). For the sake of simplicity, let us ignore atmospheric friction, I would first like to understand the relationship between planetary mass, desired orbit and necessary velocity change.

Expanding further on the question, does this calculation apply equally to orbiting very massive bodies, such as black holes? I would imagine that close to the event horizon, the high speeds of the vessel would lead to friction with space dust that might be accumulated around the accretion  disk.

Comment: Hi @Caeser and Welcome to Space! I've made some small edits so that your post better fits the style of the site. The first part about delta-v for an arbitrary body is certainly on-topic. I think people might comment about the second part (e.g. black holes) but a complete answer might not be on-topic here. There are [almost 200 different Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest) to choose from, and different questions may be on-topic in different sites. enjoy!

Comment: Around a black hole, you'll need relativity. Plus, I don't expect the vessel to survive the accretion disk. For other cases (newtonian), the vis-via equation will be what you are looking for.